# ADFS Cannot find certificate to validate message/token signature obtained from claims provider. Claims provider: WSFederationSTS

Tags: adfs, adfs3.0

We have our own ws-fed implementation. We created a claims trust provider in AD-FS that is pointing to our ws-fed implementation. 
The relaying party redirects to ADFS and ADFS redirects to our ws-fed implementation. ws-fed implementation issues ws-fed token. We have verified upto this with fiddler. 
ADFS gets the token and issues saml token back to relaying party. saml token didn't have name ID or subject or any claims sent.
ADFS logs following error message:
Cannot find certificate to validate message/token signature obtained from claims provider. 
Claims provider: WSFederationSTS

we are using self-signed certificate. The public key of the certificate is added to AdFS in the claims provider trust wizard.
Can anyone help with any steps we are missing.
ADFS 2016 is what we are using.